# Gradle Java FX aplication Build failed: UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, build.gradle

I am making JavaFX application as a university assignment and I want to include a .exe file of the application. However, while trying to build the application
`gradlew run` 
I ran into java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError.
My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}


version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = '13'
}

run{
    standardInput = System.in
    standardOutput = System.out
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'java.frontend.Main'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

mainClassName = 'frontend.Main'
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ah2d.png)

If I try to use grade -> build -> build and run the build/libs/"the built file" I have two errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java.frontend.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.frontend.Main
```

Comment: What is the full output of `./gradlew --version`?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_241 (Oracle Corporation 25.241-b07)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 x86

Comment: There's your problem. Gradle is using Java 1.8.0_241 but JavaFX 13 requires at least Java 11. You seem to be using an Oracle distribution anyway, which means JavaFX 8 should be included in the JDK. Why not just use that?

Comment: it throws  exception : Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

Comment: See if any of the many answers to [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929) help you.

Comment: They do not unfortunately

Comment: Then I'm not sure how to help. The solution is to either upgrade Java or, if your Java distribution includes JavaFX, stop trying to pull in JavaFX as a dependency.